# djcelery PeriodicTasks.changed method - update query running slow

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celerybeat, celeryd

I have been using celery (3.1), django-celery(3.1.17)(that is djcelery) with Django(1.9) for scheduling tasks. Recently I noticed that one update query to `PeriodicTasks`  table takes a lot of time(around 1 minute) due to which the whole process of scheduling tasks is working slow. The update query to model `PeriodicTasks` is called by `pre_save` and `pre_delete` singals on [`PeriodicTask` model](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/models.py#L300). Thus whenever a new object gets added in `PeriodicTask` table, signal triggers and calls [`PeriodicTasks.changed` method](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/models.py#L195) which simply update the same PeriodicTasks object's value again and again.

I am assuming the update query is working slow because millions of tasks gets published in a very short time and for each task same PeriodicTasks object is getting updated.

The question is(if I don't want to upgrade to celery 4.x), what is the purpose of this update(of `PeriodicTasks` object)? If I will remove the [signal call](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/models.py#L300), will it affect to the functionality of django-celery by any means?

Also just to mention, for celery4 also same signal calls on `pre_save` and `pre_delete` of [`PreodicTask` model](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/blob/master/django_celery_beat/models.py#L323) happen. So it will not help me even if I will upgrade to celery4.

#### Update

I experimented by commenting the two signal calls in `djcelery/models.py` everything is working well and good. Now the question is what is the purpose of this update call? Why the signals are called to update the same instance of `PeriodicTasks`.